# How to load image from URL in Fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to load an image from its URL in Fragment class. I'm loading the image like this:

```
try {
 // ImageView j=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_frm);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(image_url).getContent());
  Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600, 600, true);
  Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 255);
  i.setImageBitmap(conv_bm); 
 // j.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but this method is taking more time to load the image and to open it.
If I want to use `ImageLoader` class like [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http), then how to load it in Fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any 3rd party library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). Download the `.jar` file and put the it inside your `libs` folder. For more info see [Picasso's documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

in case of Fragments, use `getActivity()` instead of `context`.

For rounded `ImageView`, I use the [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) lib.

Comment: how to get Rounded Image If I m using Picasso Jar File

Comment: dude, just replace imageview with roundedeimageview in the xml and Picasso.with(context)
  .load(loadUrl)
  .placeholder(intermediateryImage)
  .error(errorImage)
  .into(YOUR_ROUNDED_IMAGEVIEW);

Comment: For Rounded Image View ...I have To Add Picasso Only Picasso Jar File In librs

Comment: When I add Layout ...And Add Picasson 2.3.4.jar file in And did Add To Build Path ....

<com.makeramen.RoundedImageView />   giving Error In Layout

Comment: I dont Have Build.gradle file .....How to Manage how to follow his read me content